# How can be explained why the specific heat of ice is twice as low as liquid water?

Tags: thermodynamics

To raise the temperature one degree of ice costs about 2000J but for liquid water it is 4000J.
The reason for that is that the freedoms of vibrations rotation and translations of ice are lower and the molecules of liquid can move more freely.

But I don't understand that. I would say that when molecules can move more freely it would take less energy to raise it one degree, because heat is actionally movement. But why isn't that through?

Comment: I think your statement "the freedoms of vibrations rotation and translations of ice are higher" is not correct $\it{vis-\grave{a}-vis}$ liquid water.

Comment: I think you are wright, so I changed it,

Comment: I seem to recall this has something to do with how energy can go into some bending modes of the hydrogen bonds in water, but that motion isn't available in ice because the molecules are held in place too rigidly.